# Candidate function for given conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If this is homework for any course, please tell me which course it is.

I want to fit the data below with an analytical, cartesian function.
[image: candidate function in green]

Everywhere is $\frac{dy}{dx} \gt 0$. $f(0)=0$. $f(1)=1$.

Is there a candidate function which satisfies this set of conditions?

Comment: You want to fit both the figure and the conditions?

Comment: Yes, the data to be fit are the red line points.  The green is the general form including the fact that the slope never becomes negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try $f(x)=x+0.044 \sin (7\pi x )$ - its' plot looks a little like the green plot.

Plot: 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot(%7Bx,x%2B0.044+sin(7%5Cpi+x)%7D,+%7Bx,0,1%7D)

It also have positive derivative:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot(d(x%2B0.044+sin(7%5Cpi+x),x),+%7Bx,0,1%7D)